# Added new field is not saved in mongodb in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

**grading.rb**

```
 class Grading
  require 'autoinc'
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Autoinc

  field :quantity, type: Float
  field :count, :type => Float
  field :grade_id, type: Integer
  field :batch_id, type: Integer
  field :variety_id, type: Integer
  field :serial_id, :type => Integer
  field :soaked, :type => Boolean
  # Mongoid AutoInc
  increments :serial_id

  # Associations
  belongs_to :grade
  belongs_to :variety
  belongs_to :batch
  has_many :grading_weighments, :dependent=> :destroy
  # validations
  validates_presence_of :grade_id,:batch_id,:variety_id 
  validates_presence_of :quantity , numericality: {:greater_than => 0}
  validates_presence_of :count ,numericality: {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 10, :less_than_or_equal_to => 150}
  attr_accessor :weights
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :grading_weighments, :allow_destroy => true

end
```

**gradingcontroller.rb**

```
    class GradingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_grading, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  # load_and_authorize_resource
  # GET /gradings
  # GET /gradings.json
  def index
    @gradings = Grading.all.order('date DESC')
    @q = Batch.search(params[:q])
    @batches = @q.result(:distinct  => true).in(status:["HLQDone","GradingDone"]).order('updated_at ASC').page(params[:page]).per(5)
    # @batches = Batch.all.order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(5) .where(status: "HLQ_Done")
    @grades = Grade.all.map{|g| [g.id.to_s,g.name]}
    @varieties = Variety.all.map{|v| [v.id.to_s,v.name]}
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
    end
  end

  # GET /gradings/1
  # GET /gradings/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /gradings/new
  def new
    @grading = Grading.new
  end

  # GET /gradings/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /gradings
  # POST /gradings.json
  def create
    @grades = Grade.all.map{|g| [g.id.to_s,g.name]}
    @varieties = Variety.all.map{|v| [v.id.to_s,v.name]}
    @grading = Grading.new(grading_params)
    @batch= @grading.batch
    weights=params[:grading][:weights]
    @grading.quantity= weights.map! { |i| i.to_f }.sum
    respond_to do |format|
      if @grading.save
        @grading_weighments=GradingWeighment.new
        @grading_weighments.grading_id =@grading.id
        @grading_weighments.weights =weights.join(',')
        @grading_weighments.save
        format.html { redirect_to gradings_path, notice: 'Grading was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @grading }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @grading.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /gradings/1
  # PATCH/PUT /gradings/1.json
  def update
        g=[]
        puts "#{params[:grading][:grading_weighments_attributes]}"
        params[:grading][:grading_weighments_attributes].each do |key,value|
          g<<value[:weights]
        end
        puts "=============#{g}"
        q= g.map{ |i| i.to_f }.sum
        puts "==========aes==#{q}"
        @grading.update_attributes(quantity: q)
        @gw= GradingWeighment.find_or_create_by(grading_id: @grading.id)
        @gw.update_attributes(weights: g.join(','))

    respond_to do |format|
      if @grading.update(grading_params)
        @grades = Grade.all.map{|g| [g.id.to_s,g.name]}
        @varieties = Variety.all.map{|v| [v.id.to_s,v.name]}
        format.html { redirect_to gradings_path, notice: 'Grading was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { respond_with_bip(@grading) }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @grading.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /gradings/1
  # DELETE /gradings/1.json
  def destroy
    @grading_id=@grading.id
    batch_number= @grading.batch.batch_number
    @grading.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      @del_batch = Batch.find_by(batch_number: batch_number)
      @length=@del_batch.gradings.length
      @del_batch.update_attributes(status: "HLQ_Done") if @length==0
      format.html { redirect_to gradings_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
      format.js
    end
  end
  def fetch_weights
    @grading_weighments=GradingWeighment.find_by(grading_id: params[:id]).weights
    @grading=Grading.find(params[:id])
    (@grading.grading_weighments.first.weights.split(',').length-1).times {@grading.grading_weighments.build}

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :nothing => true, :status => 200, :content_type => 'text/html'}
      format.json { head :no_content }
      format.js
    end
  end
  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_grading
      @grading = Grading.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def grading_params
      params.require(:grading).permit(:quantity,:batch_id,:variety_id,:grade_id,:count, :weights,:grading_weighments_attributes, :soaked)
    end
end
```

**list.html.erb**

```
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Count</th>
            <th>Grade</th>
            <th>Variety</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Soaked</th>
            <th>Actions</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

          <%batch= @batch if !batch%>
          <%if batch.gradings.length==0%>
          <tr><td colspan="5" class="warning">Grading is not done for batch with number <%=batch.batch_number%></td></tr>
          <%else%>
            <%gradings=batch.gradings.order('created_at DESC')%>
            <%gradings.each do |grading|%>

              <tr id="<%=grading.id%>">
                <td><%= best_in_place grading, :count, :as => :input, required:true%></td>
                <td><%= best_in_place grading, :grade_id, :as => :select, :collection => @grades %></td>
                <td><%= best_in_place grading, :variety_id, :as => :select, :collection => @varieties %></td>
                <td><%= best_in_place grading, :quantity, :as => :input%></td>
               <td><%= best_in_place grading, :soaked, :as => :input,  required:true%></td>

                <td>
                  <%= link_to "getweights/#{grading.id}", method: :get, :remote => true ,class:'btn btn-info' do%>
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                  <% end %>
                  <%= link_to grading, method: :delete, remote:true,data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } ,title:'Delete this grading', class:'btn btn-danger' do%>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                  <%end%>

                </td>
              </tr>
            <%end%>
          <%end%>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

**new.grading.html.erb**

```
<div class="form-group">
 <%= f.label :soaked ,class:"sr-only"%>
 <%= f.select :soaked ,options_for_select(["Soaked", "Un-soaked"]), {:include_blank => "Select Soaking"}, class: "form-control" ,   autocomplete:"off", required: true %>
  </div>
```

Here i am added new field called as "field :soaked, :type => Boolean", this field is not saved in database and not showing in views. How can solve this problem please help me.

Note: I passed grading params (soaked) also.

Comment: You should probably set `0` for false and `1` for true for this to work

Comment: you mean in new.grading.html.erb file

Comment: yes. btw why not to clear code (too much unnecessary one)?

Comment: i am new to rails so please write detailed code how's it possible

Comment: try code from my answer. If it fails for Mongoid, then replace true->1 and false->0

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<%= f.select :active, [['Soaked', true], ['Un-soaked', false]] %>
```

Answer (score 0):

soaked will only accept `TRUE` or `FALSE`, while you are trying to save  `"Soaked", "Un-soaked"`

```
<%= f.check_box :soaked %>
```

You can use `CHECKBOX`.

If you still want to use `"Soaked"` and  `"Un-soaked"`. You can apply check in your controller. If `Soaked` is selected then save `TRUE` else `FALSE`

Try This One

```
<%= f.select :soaked, options_for_select([['Soaked', true], ['Un-soaked', false]]) %>
```

Comment: can i change
<%= f.select :soaked ,options_for_select(["0", "1"]), {:include_blank => "Select Soaking"}, class: "form-control" ,   autocomplete:"off", required: true %>
you said like this

Comment: when i changed <%= f.check_box :Soaked %> like this total field not visible.

Comment: Try this <%= f.select :soaked, options_for_select([['Soaked', true], ['Un-soaked', false]]) %>

Comment: <%= f.check_box :Soaked %>  Here you put S(capital S) - there should be s(small s) - like <%= f.check_box :soaked %>

Comment: while it was passed the values but not stored and displayed.

Comment: ThanQ woked form me yar